# Optional Error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

While writing a UI for Swift that  tales user input into and writes the info into arrays, the "getCommand()" function with the "readLine()!" statement returns the error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" I don't know how to fix it with Optional Binding.

```
import Foundation
    struct StatsVC {
        var data = [String : Stats]()
        var current = ""
        func getCommand() -> [String] {
            print("Command" , terminator : "...")
            return splitStrPar(readLine()!) //the troublemaker
        }
        mutating func runStats() {
            print("Hello, Welcome to the Krantz UI! Please enter your stats: ")
            var command = getCommand()
            var infoData: [Stats] = []
            while(command[0] != "quit") {
                switch command[0] {
                    case "current" : //code not important here, deleted other options for simplicity
                    default : print("I don't have that command in my system")
                }
                command = getCommand()
                if(command[0] == "quit") {
                    print("Krantz Laboratories Thanks You For a Productive Session")
                }
            }
        }
    }
//statsVC.swift
func splitStrPar(_ expression: String) -> [String]{
    return expression.split{$0 == " "}.map{ String($0) }
}
func splitStrLin(_ expression: String) -> [String]{
    return expression.split{$0 == "\n"}.map{ String($0) }
}
//stats.swift
import Foundation
struct Stats {
  var values: [Double]
  init(values: [Double]){
    self.values = values
  }
//other functions not important here
}
//main.swift
var vc = StatsVC()
vc.runStats()
```

Comment: Any exclamation mark is an invitation *"Please crash me!"*. Don't force unwrap `readLine()`, unwrap it safely.

Answer (score 1):

Change your struct code to the following to properly handle optional wrappers. It is poor practice to use the forced optional wrapper postfix operator `!`. I also took the liberty of modifying your iteration through the commands array to better accomplish what I think you are trying to do.

```swift
struct StatsVC {
    var data = [String : Stats]()
    var current = ""
    func getCommands() -> [String] {
        print("Command" , terminator : "...")
        guard let line = readLine() else { return [] }
        return splitStrPar(line)
    }
    mutating func runStats() {
        print("Hello, Welcome to the Krantz CLI! Please enter your stats: ")
        let commands = getCommands()
        var infoData: [Stats] = []
        for command in commands {
            switch command {
            case "current" :
                break //code not important here, deleted other options for simplicity
            case "quit":
                print("Krantz Laboratories Thanks You For a Productive Session")
                return
            default :
                print("I don't have that command in my system")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a `guard let` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Semantically, both statements would be identical and provide no added readability, in this particular case, leaving this to be a style decision, but I like guard statements so I updated my answer to include it

Comment: You're partly right. In the end it doesn't matter for the result, but I think it increases the readability, because it makes more clear, that without a result of `readLines()` the further execution makes no sense. 
Thanks for updating